# Xcode UI Tests - Stop testing when any given test in the test suite fails?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I want to run my UI tests in such a way that if any given test within a test suite we're to fail, the entire test run is stopped. I understand there is an option to continue after failure, but this only applies to a single test case.

I plan on running the UI tests on a CI server such as Teamcity, naturally I want the build process to fail if any of the tests fail without having to wait for remaining tests to complete. Does anyone know if this is possible or will I need to somehow parse the output of each test case to detect a failure and stop at that point, possibly with some exit code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to use `fastlane` for this. You can configure your tests there as `fastlane` has a particular flag called `stop_after_first_error`, which basically does the thing you want!

You can find it here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

Comment: `stop_after_first_error` is for `snapshot` not `scan`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any way to do this natively. You might want to reconsider how you're writing UI tests, because you shouldn't have to do this. That being said, here's something you can do; it might be a bit of a hack.

Create a boolean flag like `lastTestPassed`. When an assertion is true, set the flag to true. Then, in the `setUp` method, check if `lastTestPassed` is true. If it is, then set it to false; if it isn't, then don't allow the test to run (maybe use an `XCTFail()`).

Again, this is a bit of a hack, but might work until you can refactor how your UI tests work.